# Why can't I set my label to my self click count?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

my ui main window contains:

```
self.clickcount = 0
```

This is my button press:

```
def nextApplicant(self):
    self.clickcount += 1
    print(self.clickcount)
    self.label_4.setText(clickcount)
```

so print(self.clickcount) prints no problem but I can't use it for anything else. It wont appear in my label. I can't send it to a text document. What's going on here?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QFile, QFileInfo, QTextStream
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QComboBox, QLabel, QLineEdit, QApplication, QGridLayout, \
    QCompleter, QFormLayout, QStackedLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime, date
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
from shutil import copy2
import cv2
import configparser
import ctypes
import errno
import getpass
import glob
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import pdfrw
import re
import requests
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import unittest
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import threading
import sys
import time
import threading
import socket


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(552, 285)
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(0.8)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 170, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 501, 131))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 160, 221, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 210, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.clickcount = 0 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.nextApplicant)


        self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(14)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "sdfsdf"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "N/A"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NEXT"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MERGE"))


    def nextApplicant(self):
        self.clickcount += 1
        print(self.clickcount)
        self.label_4.setText(self.clickcount)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys         
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QColor(234, 234, 234))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QColor(42, 50, 53))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(12, 15, 16))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QColor(234, 234, 234))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, QColor(100, 215, 222))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Link, QColor(126, 71, 130))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Light, Qt.black)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Shadow, QColor(12, 15, 16))
    MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.clickcount` != `clickcount`

Comment: i've tried self.label_4.setText(self.clickcount). is that what you mean? it didn't work either.

Comment: In that case please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Where do you want to use it? It could be a scope issue. But there is to little information. Check here to see how to better the question so that we can help you better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a reproducible example. please see above.

Comment: In the code you provided, I couldn't find a call to the NextApplication() function that you were reffering to..

Comment: there is no next application. I'm just trying to change the text on my label from 1, to 2, to 3, depending on how many times i click.

Comment: next applicant button is linked here: self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.nextApplicant)

Comment: @topredBird12355 1. [`setText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) only accepts strings, not number; this is Python, not PHP (luckily) or javascript. 2. Always try running your code in a terminal or prompt: in your case, you'd have seen a warning about the above; 3. The word "minimal" of "minimal reproducible example" also refers to removing things that are *not* important for your question (like setting the palette). 4. You **really** need to make up your mind about your imports, as 80% of them are completely useless, and 80% of the remainder is also redundant or poorly written.

Comment: @topredBird12355 to clarify: your code has 120 lines, 40 (A THIRD!) of them for the imports, of which just **one** line is actually necessary: `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets`. Assuming you removed the palette part (or just used the `QtGui.` prefix for QColor), the code would have reduced exactly by half. Also, be aware that editing pyuic generated files is considered a bad practice (the warning you ignored and removed is exactly about that), and you should follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to assign the value of the `self.clickcount` variable to the `self.label_4` label, you need to convert the value of `self.clickcount` to a string since the setText method takes a string as an argument.

```py
def nextApplicant(self):
    self.clickcount += 1
    print(self.clickcount)
    self.label_4.setText(str(self.clickcount))
```

[image]

Comment: pretty sure I tried this and failed but your code works! thank you so much